# Time capsule router performance

Tags: time-capsule, router

Just bought latest generation 2Tb Time Capsule that replaced my old USB drive for Time Machine backups and my Belkin G router. Everything runs fine except when I start downloading torrents. With Belkin, I could run several downloads, work remotely on three machines, and my wife could be streaming Netflix over Apple TV. Now, with Transmission running a 2.1MB/s download and no Netflix streaming, my remote connections feel like I am on dial-up. This is really disappointing. Any suggestions on how to fix it? I know I can throttle the torrents but I also frequently download large files for work and I can't just sit there waiting for download to finish before I can continue working remotely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TC router really isn't as great as it could be, I would go back to using the belkin as your wireless network and have the TC running from it.

I have a 500gb TC used on a SKY router, I have used it as a router, but also found it was slow.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about latency.

Torrenting has a tendency to open an unusually high number of concurrent connections that create a lot of chatter on the network and exhaust the router's memory by overloading the NAT cache. 'Feels like a 56k connection' can be a symptom that your router is having difficulty handling the load. A high number of dropped packets (requiring re-transmission) is another.

An quick fix is to simply reduce the number of connections. Unless you're swarm peers all have very slow upstream bandwidth, it shouldn't impact your download speed much.

*Note: The NAT Cache is where the router stores the mapping of connections between the remote user public IP and the local user's private IP.*

You can configure it in Transmission under...

```
Transmission->Preferences->Peers->Global Number of Connections
```

Manufacturers (incl Apple) have a tendency to cheap out on the router hardware because it won't have a negative impact on the 'average' user.

*SideNote: The lack of QOS capabilities on the TC is pretty lame.*